# Exit function in a game

Tags: python, exit

I'm trying to define an exit function in the game that will allow me to exit at anytime during game play. I want to add it in my main menu but I'm a bit lost. Here is my current menu so far.

```
def main_menu():
    # Print instructions and intro
    print_slow(Fore.BLUE + "Dragon Adventure Game")
    print_slow("You are John Snow the Dragon Slayer")
    print_slow("Daenerys Targaryen is holding the township hostage with her Dragon")
    print_slow("You have been summoned by King Robert Baratheon to slay the Mighty Drögon")
    print_slow("You MUST collect all 6 items to slay Drögon, or perish in a ball of flames.")
    print_slow("Move commands: go South, go North, go East, go West")
    print_slow("Add to Inventory: get 'item name'" + Fore.RESET)
```

Comment: First figure out how you get user input.  If console text, is the usual Ctrl+C enough?

Comment: `if command == 'quit': quit()` will exit the Python interpreter.

Comment: Just a tip, consider using a multiline string here instead of many individual print statements

Comment: Thanks, I'm still new to this so I'll work on that.